# Why Chaincode instantiate giving error trying to connect to local peer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Hi Everyone I have successfully installed the chaincode on my all peers. So when I am trying to instantiate chaincode it is giving me following error which are mentioned below. Please help me with this , I am new to this thing so may be i missed somewhere something. I have referred some of the question related to this but i did not get anything.

First Command -

```
root@7485ef4909d6:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.indirasoft.com:7050 -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n fabcar -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":[""]}' -P "OR ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member','Org3MSP.member','Org4MSP.member','Org5MSP.member')"
```

Error -

> 2018-10-29 18:01:51.158 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams ->
>   INFO 001 Using default escc 2018-10-29 18:01:51.158 UTC [chaincodeCmd]
>   checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc Error: could
>   not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful,
>   error code 500, msg timeout expired while starting chaincode
>   fabcar:1.0 for transaction

Second Command -

```
root@7485ef4909d6:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.indirasoft.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/indirasoft.com/orderers/orderer.indirasoft.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.indirasoft.com-cert.pem -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n fabcar -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":[""]}' -P "OR ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member','Org3MSP.member','Org4MSP.member','Org5MSP.member')"
```

Error -

> 2018-10-29 17:50:49.094 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams ->
>   INFO 001 Using default escc 2018-10-29 17:50:49.094 UTC [chaincodeCmd]
>   checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc Error: could
>   not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful,
>   error code 500, msg timeout expired while starting chaincode
>   fabcar:1.0 for transaction

It use to create on container but it goes to excited mode.
Below is the log for that container.

```
> 2018-10-29 18:02:10.883 UTC [shim] userChaincodeStreamGetter -> ERRO 001 context deadline exceeded
error trying to connect to local peer
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim.userChaincodeStreamGetter
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/chaincode.go:112
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim.Start
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/chaincode.go:151
main.main
    /chaincode/input/src/github.com/chaincode/fabcar/go/fabcar.go:200
runtime.main
    /opt/go/src/runtime/proc.go:198
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361
Error creating new Smart Contract: error trying to connect to local peer: context deadline exceeded
```

All docker containers -

[image: See Here All docker containers running]

Use below link to seer Peer0.org1 complete log -
[Peer Log Check here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VAKGDQo8LBCuTKjzWrHFlmSDu1Vrwl3z)

Use below link to see docker_compose file -
[Docker-compose.yaml](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZqYXjjgvWOVyJSbhrrb5rbM0bg0Fx8_y)

Use below link to see support  file i.e base -

[Base.yaml](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1f8b8T1FkDKmdj2FeppPklE7LjOlV-cs4)

How can i solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52059775/hyperledger-fabric-with-kubernetes-not-able-to-instantiate-chaincode

Comment: Where i can add, that environment variable? Is that i have to define in crypto-config file? @adnan.c

Comment: if you are using docker to bring up a network, then its in the docker-compose file.

Comment: yes i am using docker. So should i add this to all peer env. variable and orderer. @adnan.c

Comment: I have added that env variable to every peer and orderer but still i am getting same issue.  @adnan.c

Comment: please add the results of `docker ps -a` and the peer log.

Comment: @adnan.c I have edited my post and added peer log. Since last two days i am having same problem. Unable to find any solution. Please help me out with this. If any thing required let me know.

Comment: try setting "core_peer_address" in the following way: `CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051`

Comment: @adnan.c I have edited my post and added docker-compose and base.yaml file. Can you please check. "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051" This i have used but still same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both peer4 and peer5 are exposing the same port 10056. Not sure if that's the root cause but is certainly first thing to fix.